# Unable to record various events using Mobile application with loadrunner

Tags: android, loadrunner, recording

I am trying to record an android application with Load-runner using the emulator. I am using the `MobileHTTP` protocol.

I am getting an error, `"Server terminated the connection"`, and I am unable to record any type of events other than HTTP events in the app. Please suggest any other way to record an application via load-runner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> and I am unable to record any type of events other than HTTP events in the app

You selected the Mobile HTTP protocol. Why would you expect anything other than HTTP to be recorded?

Comment: Thankyou for your response James. I figured it out few days back. Now I am using TruClient Native Mobile Application protocol for the same.